# How do I show and hide a DIV using this method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show and hide a DIV using a button which I have programmed to change text using the data-text-swap method (which I found online). My DIV is set to 'display: none' in CSS but I want to change this using Javascript. What am I doing wrong in my code?

```js
var showMixerBtn = document.getElementById("showMixer");
  showMixerBtn.addEventListener("click", showMixerBtnActions);

  function showMixerBtnActions() {
   if (showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == showMixerBtn.innerHTML) {
    showMixerBtn.innerHTML = showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-original");
   }
   else {
    showMixerBtn.setAttribute("data-text-original", showMixerBtn.innerHTML);
    showMixerBtn.innerHTML = showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
   }
  }

  var mixerSliders = document.getElementById("mixerSliders");
  mixerSliders.addEventListener("click", showMixerActions);

  function showMixerActions() {
   if (showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-original")) {
    mixerSliders.style.display = "block";
   }
   else {
    mixerSliders.style.display = "none";
   }
  }
```

```css
div#mixerSliders {
   display: none;
  }
```

```html
<button id="showMixer" data-text-swap="Hide Mixer">Show Mixer</button>

<div id="mixerSliders">
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="kickSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="snareSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="clapSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="cHatSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="oHatSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="tomSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="perc1Slider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="perc2Slider" nx="slider"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where is `mixerSliders`? Please add the relevant code to replicate your problem..

Comment: apologies added now

Comment: Your 'mixerSliders' element is not display by default based on the CSS.  So, user can never trigger this "mixerSliders.addEventListener("click", showMixerActions);"

Comment: Your listener for showing and hiding the slider has been added to the slider itself. When it is hidden, how can a user click on it to make it display? The displaying of the slider needs to be tied to the show / hide button (just make it part of the first function would be the easiest solution)

Comment: @shokulei if i remove the CSS code it still doesn't work, but i want the mixerSliders to initially be display: none by default when the page loads

Comment: @mikeg542 ah yes i didnt realise that, i've changed it and it now shows the sliders if the button is pressed but doesn't hide the sliders if the button is pressed again

Comment: @AlfieMitchell, remember that you canvas is showing as white spaces since there is no CSS style for it.

Comment: If something worked for you, remember to mark off a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var showMixerBtn = document.getElementById("showMixer");
  showMixerBtn.addEventListener("click", showMixerBtnActions);

  function showMixerBtnActions() {
   if (showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-swap") == showMixerBtn.innerHTML) {
    showMixerBtn.innerHTML = showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-original");
        mixerSliders.style.display = "none";
   }
   else {
    showMixerBtn.setAttribute("data-text-original", showMixerBtn.innerHTML);
    showMixerBtn.innerHTML = showMixerBtn.getAttribute("data-text-swap");
        mixerSliders.style.display = "block";
   }
  }
```

```css
div#mixerSliders {
   display: none;
  }

.gainSliders {
  border: 2px inset brown;
}
```

```html
<button id="showMixer" data-text-swap="Hide Mixer">Show Mixer</button>

<div id="mixerSliders">
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="kickSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="snareSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="clapSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="cHatSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="oHatSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="tomSlider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="perc1Slider" nx="slider"></canvas>
  <canvas class="gainSliders" id="perc2Slider" nx="slider"></canvas>
 </div>
```

This will make the text change and the slide show or hide as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I did differently , rather than using display none , as you are using jquery you can use toggle function , it will easy up the things

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
    
       
        var el = $(this);
        el.text() == el.data("text-swap") 
         ? el.text(el.data("text-original")) 
         : el.text(el.data("text-swap"));
    
        $("p").toggle();
       
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>

<button id="hide" data-text-swap="Hide" data-text-original="Show">Hide</button>


</body>
```

Comment: thanks, as this is practise for uni assignment i'm only allowed to use plain javascript but will bear this in mind for future coding